# Select difference between layers in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, contrast, cc-2017

I am working with **Photoshop CC 2017**. I'm trying to create an **Action Sequence** picture.

So the photos I'll use as example are of a biker performing a jump: [image: Full picture]

But since one of the "bikers" is fully in front of a tree I want **to select him** and add some **contrast** between *him* and the *background*. Which is the best way I can **select** *him*? 
(Maybe a function to find huge **differences** between pixels in layers?)

This is the image with the person in front of a tree: [image: 1]

This is a picture with only the background on his spot: [image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the two pictures into separate layers and set the top one to "Difference" in the layers palette.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Post a better answer or edit to improve mine. The brevity of the answer is sufficient for this question.